# Saving in localSettings when push notification recieved when the app is in background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to save a flag when a push notification is arrived on the phone. I am able to achieve that when the app is foreground. But when the app is closed or in background , it doesnt work . The code is as follows

```
 await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");
 ParsePush.ToastNotificationReceived += OnPushNotification;

 private async void OnPushNotification(object sender,Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values["Add"] = "true";
    }
```

Is there any way by which i can save the LocalSettings even when the app is closed or in background. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'app is closed or in background'? When app is closed how it can perform any code?

Comment: I am sorry i am new to windows , i had been working with android before, so i was looking something similiar to broadcast receiver in android. I need to open a specific page(not the mainpage) when tapped on notification. However i am using parse.com, which doesnt give any option to add param tags. So as a workaround i thought of saving it in a variable in localsetting and based on that i could check if it has to show main page or to redirect to the page to be shown on receiving notification

Comment: As for app lifecycle, you should definitely read [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx). As for receiving notification once the app is closed/suspended/inactive, you will need a background task for this - [here is some help at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710184.aspx) and [also here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709906.aspx).